# Pyspark: Forward filling nulls with last value

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
values = [
    ("2019-10-01", "004", 1.0),
    ("2019-10-02", "005", None),
    ("2019-10-03", "004", 2.0),
    ("2019-10-04", "004", 1.0),
    ("2019-10-05", "006", None)

] 

df = spark.createDataFrame(values, ['time', 'mode', 'value'])
```

I want to fill the None's in the last column with the previous non-null value.

```
    ("2019-10-01", "004", 1.0),
    ("2019-10-02", "005", 1.0),
    ("2019-10-03", "004", 2.0),
    ("2019-10-04", "004", 1.0),
    ("2019-10-05", "006", 1.0)
```

I tried this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df_2 = df.withColumn("value2", f.last('value', ignorenulls=True).over(Window.orderBy('time').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))
```

This does not work as there are still nulls in the new column.
How can I forward-fill the last column?

Answer (score 3):

There is just a tiny mistake with your windowing, try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f, Window

window_last = Window.orderBy("time")

df_2 = df.withColumn("value2", f.last("value", ignorenulls=True).over(window_last))
```

Result:

```
+----------+----+-----+------+
|      time|mode|value|value2|
+----------+----+-----+------+
|2019-10-01| 004|  1.0|   1.0|
|2019-10-02| 005| null|   1.0|
|2019-10-03| 004|  2.0|   2.0|
|2019-10-04| 004|  1.0|   1.0|
|2019-10-05| 006| null|   1.0|
+----------+----+-----+------+
```

Comment: This also does not work for my dataset, I still get null's. The characteristic of my dataset is that it mainly contains null's as value and just a few non-null values (many thousand nulls between two values).

Comment: I solved it. The problem was that I had too much data (with null-values). I filtered the whole dataset to the most relevant rows, then it worked

Comment: The size of your dataset does not change the way this function behave. I believe your dataset starts with null values and keeps with nulls for some time before its first non-null value appears.